# text-overflow not working when parent div randomly sized?

Tags: html, css

I've got a wall of images, which the sizes are constricted somewhat randomly to best fit the DOM width.

These images are stored in a div container, along with text that shows the image name when you hover your mouse over it.

[image]

Now the image wall itself works fine, however, I'm having a small styling issue.

When the image is small and the text overflows the text span, `text-overflow: ellipsis;` does nothing. In fact, the text would just keep going if it wasn't for the container having `overflow:hidden;`.

To demonstrate, I've put `border: 1px solid red;` on the text span to show you that the text is indeed overflowing, despite the width of the container not increasing.

Why is this happening?

Comment: please provide code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add white-space: nowrap and overflow:hidden to the class.

Answer (score 0):

> When the image is small and the text overflows the text span, text-overflow: ellipsis; does nothing. In fact, the text would just keep going if it wasn't for the container having overflow:hidden;...Why is this happening?

Indeed the text overflow property display the text visible in an overflowed container where parts or sections of the text are hidden by the parent container.That is an `overflow:hidden` property must be set by the parent container.

To support this here is what MDN has to say about this

> The text-overflow CSS property determines how overflowed content that
>   **is not displayed** is signaled to users....This CSS property doesn't force an overflow to occur; to do so and make text-overflow to be applied, **the author must apply some additional properties on the element, like setting overflow to hidden.**

The link is taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)